# SQLite "On delete CASCADE" not cascading in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a database in Qt.
it has four tables: maingroup, subgroup, parts, and position.this is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `maingroup` (
    `groupName`TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     PRIMARY KEY(`groupName`)
);
CREATE TABLE `subgroup` (
    `sub`   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `main`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`sub`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`main`) REFERENCES `maingroup`(`groupName`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE `parts` (
    `ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `Part_Number`   TEXT,
    `Type`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `Value` TEXT,
    `Voltage`   TEXT,
    `Quantity`  TEXT,
    `Position`  TEXT,
    `Picture`   TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(`Position`) REFERENCES `Position`(`Poistion`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`Type`) REFERENCES `subgroup`(`sub`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Type in table parts is foreign key refers to column sub from table subgroup.
main in table subgroup is foreign key refers to column groupname in table maingroup.
my problem is when I try (`delete from maingroup WHERE groupName= 'dd';`) in DB Browser it deletes both parent and children.
But in QT this command(`myQuery.exec("delete from maingroup WHERE groupName= 'dd'");`) just deletes the parent field in maingroup table and not the child in subgroup  and part table and the main column in subgroup table refers to a field in maingroup table that does not exist.
what is wrong here?what should i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to turn on the foreign-key pragma by executing another statement before your DELETE statement.

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
q.exec("DELETE FROM ...");
```

This was able to cascade deletes, and should also be sufficient to solve other foreign-key related issues.

*Credits to [this forum.qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/77967/foreign-key-is-ignored-when-deleting/2) post.*

Comment: thank you so much. I thought that its enough to enable it in db browser.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @TrebledJ correct and very helpful answer it's worth to mention two additional characteristics about the foreign-key pragma (in connection with Qt):

**1. The pragma can set via QSqlDatabase, too.**

So the following code has the same effect as @TrebledJ's example:

```
auto database = QSqlDatabase::database();
database.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
QSqlQuery query(database); // query "inherits" the pragma from database
query.exec("DELETE FROM ...");
```

**2. This behavior even applies if opening and using the database happens at different places in the program.**

Still the same effect:

Somewhere in initialization code:
    // this calls database.open() implicit because database was not open before.
    auto database = QSqlDatabase::database();

```
QSqlDatabase::database();
database.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
// make sure database.close() is NOT called!
```

Somewhere else in code

```
// you'll get the instance of your initialization code because database is already open (so QSqlDatabase::database() implements a singleton pattern).
// so pragma foreign_keys is still set to "ON"
auto database = QSqlDatabase::database();

QSqlQuery query(database);
query.exec("DELETE FROM ...");
```

This might be important to know if you want to understand why the foreign_keys pragma seems to only sometimes apply in your project (and sometimes not).

**What I did**

So I came to the conclusion to make sure to have ONE distinct place in my code where to explicit open the database (and configure the connection):

```
QString dbConnectionName = "My project database";
auto database = QSqlDatabase::database(dbConnectionName, true);
// configure the pragmas here
```

At all other places I avoid to (accidentally) open the database:

```
auto database = QSqlDatabase::database(dbConnectionName, false);
// e.g. use the database via queries ...
```